# How can I get attachment content from an Outlook mail in a Node.js Outlook add-in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, outlook, outlook-addin, email-attachments

First of all, being a student, I lack some experience to understand everything about what I tried and what I try. But still, I feel like I've tried pretty much every solution available on the net.

I'm developing a Yeoman based Outlook add-in (full javascript with Node.js) for my company, and I came to the point where I need to get the attachments from a mail, not just the informations like size, file type or name of the attachments, I need the full content, in base64 if possible (in order to produce a .eml file containing the mail body and attached files).

I've found multiple ways to do so, problem is none of them work :

- first I tried with the messy microsoft documentation, and the first solution that I found is this one : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item, problem is that with this solution I need to make use of c#, but my add-in is full js, and I need to find a solution that works with JS and Node.js
- then I looked for a solution that allows me to communicate a way or another with the Exchange Server to get the attachments content, and I found this : https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-javascript-api, but this was not working with browser oriented add-in (and I need my add-in to work on both client and browsers), so I made use of this : https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-js-api-browser. I found some code samples in the first link and here : [Save outlook Email attachment using ews-javascript-api npm in node JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508542/save-outlook-email-attachment-using-ews-javascript-api-npm-in-node-js) that helped me build something (using the second link's example's syntax on the third link's sample code) that was supposed to work, but coming to the point where I'm trying to get the attachments from the mail, I get a lot of informations from the attachment, but anything related to it's content is null, and the next step where I "Load" the file returns an error 500 from the "service" with "the document is empty", and I still don't know why yet.
- finally, I tried to take a step back, looking on google for office api and how to get attachment content, and I've found this link : https://blog.mastykarz.nl/office-365-unified-api-mail/ that almost looked to good to be true, and I was right : according to microsoft doc, I need a token in order to make work the office 365 api url, token given by Azure AD when an administrator authorizes you to obtain it (or so do I think, this is the part where the microsoft doc is the messier). Problem is, while connecting on Azure AD, I get an error displaying on the screen from the website (absolutely no details about the error), and some places that I need to access in order to get my token just wont work, displaying another error message without any details or just never loading.

I've reduced as much as possible the size of my question, not wanting to drown you under informations, sample codes, links and pics so, sorry if it may look both too long and too poor in details.

Thank you for your time, feel free to give any solution, suggestion or advice that come to your mind !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doing the same thing, solution I found:

- Get exchangeToken in client (`Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync()`)
- Send token, attachmentsIds, emailID to server (C# in my case, nodejs in your case)
- Use EWS Managed API 2.0 or in your case [ews-javascript-api](https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-javascript-api) to handle loading email mimecontent (contains email + attachments) or attachment mimecontent.
- Upload file to another service or do whatever you want with it.

Before I switched to C# for serverside I was using a nodejs one for testing, so if you have questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm getting the token correctly, but now as you said I need to send both token and datas to my nodejs server, getting them elsewhere I guess. To do so, I installed ews-javascript-api, but when I `require` it, my compiler tells me that both `dns` and `net` couldn't be resolved in 'node_modules\fetch\lib', so I installed them, and now I've got the same problem with `dgram` but installing it doesn't change a thing
Beside, I don't know what to do with my token, using ews-javascript-api. Where do I need it ?

Comment: The `fetch` library is only awailable in the browser. `ews-javascript-api` works only in the context of a nodejs server, for the client(browser) you have to use `ews-js-api-browser`. Does that help ?

Comment: This is where I see that I lack experience...
So, if I got it right, I need to use `ews-js-api-browser` in my client to get the attachments from Exchange, but don't I need to send a request containing my token to my local nodejs server (or another one built for that purpose ?) in order to manage my own request on the server side, communicate with Exchange and return the attachments to my client ? Is there a difference between these 2 solutions ? Maybe I just didn't understand how one works

Comment: You CAN do everything client side using `ews-js-api-browser`, in that case you do not need a node server, but I found that I got out of memory errors because my windows/outlook combo is using an old version of IE11 as client that has a bug when dealing with large xml-responses.

Comment: OR you can use Office.js in the client to get the token and ids, send them to the server which is using `ews-javascript-api` to send the request to the exchange server.

Comment: ok now I got it. Problem is, as said in my second point, I already tried with `ews-js-api-browser`, but I get errors. Exchange send me the attachments, which are stored in a an array, but none of them has content, just infos and ids. This is where I'm stuck with this solution. And I've not found anything related to this peculiar problem on the net, it should be working at this point

Comment: Aaaaah I know what you miss :) the .getAttachments() call takes options as second parameter, you have to pass something like  `{ItemShema.MimeContent}` to it, sorry on my way home an mobile don't have the exact code handy.

Comment: I don't use this call when working with `ews-javascript-api-browser`, I just use the `FindItems(...)` call from ExchangeService, and then do a `Load(...)` on the results with the ItemSchema you're talking about in the call's parameters.
The line looks like this : `email.Load(new EwsJS.PropertySet(EwsJS.BasePropertySet.IdOnly, [EwsJS.ItemSchema.Attachments, EwsJS.ItemSchema.HasAttachments])).then(() => {...}`

Comment: Try adding `EwsJS.ItemShema.MimeContent` to that array, then you should have a base64Content in the response that you can save as .eml file. To load the individual attachments, I think you have to call forEach attachent in the response .Load() also with the MimeContent as option

Comment: Well, it worked. Better than I expected, it returns the whole mail with all the attachments. So thats two birds with one stone. Thanks for everything !

Comment: Well, at least it works on Chrome, but not on Outlook client, which doesn't seem to support the solution T_T

Comment: Use the F12 debugging tool (See the how to debug officejs doc) and set it to break on allexeptions. Do you get an 'SyntaxError' ? If yes its caused by a bug in IE11 (in my case when loading email bigger then 6-7MB). As workaround I now use a server to which I send the callbacktoken and ids of email/attachments I want to load and let the server handle the download/saving/upload.